# Using a node.js natural package client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

I want to use node's [natural](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural) package client-side.

I have a node.js app, but I want to apply porter stemmer from natural when my users add hashtags, so that those hashtags are automatically converted to their stems and are shown to user before s/he actually adds them into the database.

How would I go about implementing that?

I know there are different tools to use Node.Js packages client-side like Browserify, for example. But I would rather prefer to have access to only this package from the outside and communicate with it without the use of any extra libraries. Can I just include its scripts into the html page?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I was going to tell you about Browserify, but you already know it. What do you think about writing some REST API that deals with that library?

Comment: @gustavohenke do you think it's possible to just use the library's methods directly by including some javascripts into the code?

Comment: If you adapt the lib, well, you probably will be able to use it. But when you update the lib, this will break your app. So, I'd either use Browserify or a REST API.